# What is the difference among these words?

Tags: word-meaning

Some English words are driving me mad for their similarities when I try to momerize them. Could anyone tell me the difference between 'seduce' and 'seduct', 'seduction' and ' seducement', according to dictionary,their meanings are so similar that it is hard for me to tell them aparat.

Comment: Wow, which dictionary listed *seduct*?  I only see it in the OED, where it's listed as rare and obsolete.

Comment: the strange combination here:: seduct (v.) -> seduction (n), seduce (v.) -> seducement (n),. but currently in common use are seduce (v.) -> seduction (n)

Comment: @Shaunak Shukla: It's not a strange combination. *reduce⟶reduction, deduce⟶deduction, produce⟶production, introduce⟶introduction.* But to understand where it came from, you need to look at the Latin roots of these words.

Answer (score 2):

*Seduce* is a verb, and *seduction* is a noun = the act of seducing.

You may safely ignore the verb *seduct* and the noun *seducement*, which were never in common use and have been obsolete for at least two centuries.